# Make a more compact code of this massive list

Tags: java, loops, selenium, checkbox

So i want to make the following code more compact, is there a way?

Maybe with a loop or something. Tried a for loop but didn't really work out that well...

```
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='2']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='3']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='4']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='5']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='6']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='7']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='8']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='9']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='10']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='11']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='12']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='13']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='14']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='15']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='16']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='17']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='18']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='19']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[3]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[4]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[5]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[6]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[7]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[8]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[9]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[10]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[11]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[12]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[13]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[14]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[15]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[16]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[17]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[18]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[19]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/input[20]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button [@type='submit']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Those are two lists with checkboxes.

Comment: why loop not work? As far as i see, I think a for loop with string concatenation will work

Comment: Can you explain "didn't really work out that well"?

Comment: i messed up somewhere i guess. did almost the same as the answer of Jan down here. think i did a typo or something cause now its working. also i tried to do an if statement in there for no good reason :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
    for(int i = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='"+i+"']")).click();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

and so on for the other items?

Comment: just did, could do it before because it was to fast or something, Thanks!